# Getting inverse values of acceleration and tilt for the MPU 6050

Tags: i2c, mpu6050

I'm using the I2C library to connect to a GY-521 board and, when executing the getAcceleration() methods I get gyro values and viceversa..

This is my setup (I'm using a proto shield but that shouldn't change anything as far as I understand):

[image]

It follows this schematic:

[image]

And this is the code I'm testing:

```
#include "Wire.h"

#include "MPU6050.h"

MPU6050 accel;

int16_t ax, ay, az;

void setup() {
    Wire.begin();
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Initializing I2C devices...");
    accel.initialize();
    Serial.println("Testing device connections...");
    Serial.println(accel.testConnection() ? "Connected" : "Connection failed");
}

void loop() {
    accel.getAcceleration(&ax, &ay, &az);
    Serial.print("acc x:    ");
    Serial.println(ax);  // This prints the gyro value of the Y axis!
    delay(1000);
}
```

I don't think it has to do with the wiring since inverting the 4 and 5 analog pins yields zero values.

Is this a problem with the library? Or with my chip?

Comment: I think this has to be a problem with the library, or with your method of discerning which set of values is the accel and the gyro I guess. Gyro should be the one totally zerod out when the sensor is sitting still. Where did you download the library from?

Comment: Yup I'm sure that's the gyro value (I even have a video if you need it). So I'm guessing it's the library... I may just wrap it up with the correct names

Comment: Personally I use `accel.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);` which yields all values generated by the sensor.

Just to be certain, if you use `accelgyro.getAcceleration(&ax, &ay, &az);` you get Gyro data and if you use `accelgyro.getRotation(&gx, &gy, &gz);` you get Accelerometer data?

If you actually get the values the wrong way around, you could just use the variables in the 'wrong' way, I know this is not how it should work.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of libraries, I wouldn't use the accelerometer library in wire, download and add the I2Cdev library, you can get it on a variety of different sites like github.com

Comment: Would you please develop your answer further? Currently this is not the typical kind of useful answer: no real value, no detail, no reason why "you wouldn't use the accelerometer library..." For me, you could have posted this as a comment to the question.